# Python Parent Class Check for Attribute in Subclass To Be Used in Class Function

Tags: python, class, object, inheritance

I am writing this Python(2.7) script that is a series of menus. For each sub menu there is a child class that inherits BaseMenu. There is one subclass called SubMenu that I want  to print server_name underneath the title of the submenu name. In BaseMenu(), I tried to put a if statement to check if an attribute exists, and if so then print it:

```
def display(self):
        header = "FooBar YO"
        term = getTerminalSize()
        #sys.stdout.write("\x1b[2J\x1b[H")
        print header.center(term, '*')
        print self.menu_name.center(term, '+')
    ###Below is the check
    if self.modify_server_class:
            print self.modify_server_class.center(term, '+')
```

It didn't work and complained `AttributeError: 'Servers' object has no attribute 'modify_server_class'` when I tried to run other classes that don't have that attribute.

How should I go about have the BaseClass check this attribute and print it if it exists? I don't want to put the attribute in every class and set it to false. Seems like there could be a cleaner way.

```
class BaseMenu(object):
    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta

    @abc.abstractproperty
    def options(self):
        pass

    @abc.abstractproperty
    def menu_name(self):
        pass

    def display(self):
        header = "FooBar YO"
        term = getTerminalSize()
        #sys.stdout.write("\x1b[2J\x1b[H")
        print header.center(term, '*')
        print self.menu_name.center(term, '+')
    if self.modify_server_class:
            print self.modify_server_class.center(term, '+')
        print "Please choose which option:"
        for i in self.options:
            print(
                str(self.options.index(i)+1) + ") "
                + i.__name__
            )
        while True:
        value = int(raw_input("Please Choose[ENTER to exit]: ")) - 1

        try:
        if value == "":
            break
        else:
            #with Redirect(self.file_object):
            self.options[value](self)
            self.display()
        except IndexError:
        print "Out of range!"


class ModifyServer(BaseMenu):
    def __init__(self, a):
    self.servers_object = a

    menu_name = "Modify Server"
    server_chosen = "None"
    modify_server_class = "hi"

    def choose_server(self):
    if not self.servers_object.servers:
        cs = pyrax.cloudservers
        self.servers_object.servers = cs.servers.list()
    temp = self.servers_object.servers
    for index, item in enumerate(temp):
        print (
        "%s) %s" % (index+1, item.name)
        )

    def jj(self):
    pass

    options = (
        choose_server,
    jj
    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either create a constructor for you `BaseMenu` which sets this attribute or use `hasattr()`

Comment: I tried  if hasattr(self, self.cached_server) but Python is still complaining when other classes do not have this attribute...example: AttributeError: 'Servers' object has no attribute 'cached_server'

Comment: @dman The attribute name must be given as string: `hasattr(self, "cached_server")`